# iphone NSDate Conversion problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my graph Api for facebook..

I am getting this data..
from Json..
`"updated_time" = "2011-05-17T14:52:16+0000";`

and I am using this code to convert it into valid date format

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000  
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-ddHH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[[forTable valueForKey:@"updated_time"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@""]];
[df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];
pastDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"and the date string is %@",pastDate);
```

and it is giving me this result in the console

`and the date string is Mon 01 17, 2011 08:22`

though json value is giving me the date of May.this code is giving me the date January

can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but in your parsing format you seem to have 'mm' for the month, shouldn't it be 'MM'?  Also, the '+' might be causing problems, it looks like you parsed out the T.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like your date format string isn't taking the letter "T" into account – and you should probably be enclosing literal text between apostrophes, just to be safe.  Try:

`[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZ"];`

Answer (score 1):

The dateFormat was wrong, it should be with capital Ms for the month:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

Comment: You are missing, 'T'.