# Removing T from nsdate

Tags: objective-c

Using some api i get this date format :

```
2014-04-19T22:24:39+0000
```

Which for some reason has this T in there .

I need this NSDate object at the end :

```
2014-04-09 23:03:05 +0000
```

How would i convert the old date to the new **NSDate** ?

I have started with something like this :

```
NSDate *date=[image objectForKey:@"updated_time"]; //problematic date
NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

How would i go from here to create the new date ?

I have read this answer but did not understand it

[iphone NSDate Conversion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068387/iphone-nsdate-conversion-problem)

Comment: Doesn't it work to just change `'T'` in the format string you're showing to `' '`?

Comment: I wonder how so simple and clear question getting down voted . i really don't know what man can do more than asking so nice and clear.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're not giving much details on what is not working with the code you're showing. Most people don't want to set up a new solution just to see what's not working in code you already know the result of.

Comment: The code i show is just create a df. it does NOT create a new date. and i don't know how to create a new date from it .

Comment: What exactly wrong with this code? If I assume first line is a string with your given date, your date format creates a valid date object as expected.

Comment: If you haven't already, check out Peter Hosey's [ISO Date NSDateFormatter](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter), it is going to be more precise at handling ISO 8601 dates.   I've written similar code in the past, but Peter's is much more complete than most implementations.

Comment: @Curnelious Actually, no, it does ***not*** say "I need a date not a string", in bold or otherwise, nor does it say "how can I convert from a string in this format to an NSDate object?" That's "what man can do more": Actually *say* what you mean as clearly and specifically as possible, rather than assuming that because you know what you mean, other people "should" be able to infer what you mean and then getting upset when they find what you're saying ambiguous.

Comment: Please read Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article. And BTW, the "some reason" the T is in there is that it's an ISO-8601 international date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to any one who is facing the same problem, reading the API of Facebook:

```
NSString *date=[image objectForKey:@"updated_time"];
NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZ"];
NSDate *newdate = [df dateFromString:date];
```

That's it. Simple, and works.

Comment: See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) regarding best practice: Set the `locale` of the formatter, too.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is close, you just need to do the actual conversion, so this...

```
NSDate *date=[image objectForKey:@"updated_time"]; //problematic date
NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
```

needs to become this...

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:[image objectForKey:@"updated_time"]]; //problematic date
```

Added note, if you are expecting "HH" to return you a 24 hour clock value, you need to read this http://www.flexicoder.com/blog/index.php/2013/10/ios-24-hour-date-format/